# Hover on div not working

Tags: css, html, hover

This is the html part of my page:

```
    <div class="edenKomentar">
            <div class="rejtingVoKomentar" onmouseover="alert('asd');">
                <div class="thumbUp"> </div>
                <div class="thumbDown"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="imeVoKomentar">Name</div>
            <div class="tekstVoKomentar">Comment</div>
            <div class="datumVoKomentar">Date</div>
    </div>
```

and this is my css code:

```
div.edenKomentar:hover {
//  border-bottom: dashed 1px gray;
    border-left: solid 8px #003366;
}
div.edenKomentar:hover div.imeVoKomentar {
    color:#003366;
}

.edenKomentar div.rejtingVoKomentar {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    right:5px;
    top:15px;
    height:35px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px green;
}

.edenKomentar div.rejtingVoKomentar:hover{
    border: solid 2px green;
    background-color:#66FF00;
}


.rejtingVoKomentar .thumbUp,.thumbDown {
    position: relative ;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    top: 10px;
}
.rejtingVoKomentar .thumbDown {
    right: 5px;
    background:url(sliki/Ikoni/Thumb-down-icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.rejtingVoKomentar .thumbUp {
    left: 5px;
    background:url(sliki/Ikoni/Thumb-up-icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.rejtingVoKomentar .thumbDown:hover{
    border: solid 2px red;
}
```

The problem is that hover (and onmouseover) on .rejtingVoKomentar ( and .thumbUp and .thumbDown also) is not working while **.rejtingVoKomentar** has the

```
position:absolute;
```

attribute. What can be the problem here?

Comment: Just created a [jsfiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/cQ57w/). Now explain what is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

you will use jQuery to activate hover on DIV

or just want to use it by CSS only you will need to use ul,li instead

**UPDATE1**

check this link in SO [Jquery Div Hover change other Div Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414445/jquery-div-hover-change-other-div-class)

Comment: jQuery not working also, here is a link to the page, just try disabling position:absolute; on .rejtngVoKomentar and .thumbUp and its all working allright. The link -- [link](http://ipproekt.x10.mx/Komentari.html)

Comment: I manage to do it by changing the z-index, now I can do it with css and with jQuery. thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

```
.headermenu li a{
   text-align:center;
   padding:0px 0 0 12px;
   margin-left:20px;
   display:block;
   color: #ccc;
   text-decoration:none;
   font-size:12px;
   float:right;
   background:url(../images/arrow.png) no-repeat left center;
 }

 .headermenu li a:hover{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    color: #0066CC;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    background:url(../images/arrow_hover.png) no-repeat left center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this short Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".rejtingVoKomentar").hover(
  function () {
    //On mouseOver
    alert('asd');
  },
  function () {
    //On mouseOut
  }
);});
```